# Error loading to MySQL TPC-H data via dbgen

Tags: mysql, tpc

I am using https://github.com/electrum/tpch-dbgen to generate the 8 tables of TPC-H.
However, for the `PART` table, when loading the data to MySQL via `load infile` command,
I get via `show warnings`, tons of warnings such as:

```
| Note    | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'P_RETAILPRICE' at row 517 |
```

The sample of the data itself:

```
517|aquamarine rosy violet moccasin snow|Manufacturer#3|Brand#34|SMALL BURNISHED COPPER|30|WRAP CAN|1417.51|uses. |
```

and the table definition is taken from https://github.com/dragansah/tpch-dbgen/blob/master/tpch-create.sql

I load the data like so:

```
load data local infile '/full-path/part.tbl' into table PART columns terminated by '|';
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have had problems with the trailing `|` in the file.  To remove all trailing `|` in your table files, use this command:

```bash
sed -i 's/|$//' *.tbl
```

If that works for you then you can modify the dbgen code to do this always.
In the file `dss.h`, try adding a line like this:

```c
#define EOL_HANDLING
```